# 2 java versions and unable to change environment variable

Tags: macos, java, environment-variables

I am working on Mac OS 10.9 I did not know that macs come with java by default. So I installed my own java(version- 1.8.0_20) Now here is the confusion -

I have a java in the following locations -

```
/usr/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home//bin/java
```

whereis java returns the 1st address and which java returns the second address. So I thought something must be wrong in my environment variables. So I read up a little on that and echo $PATH returns this -

```
/usr/local/hive/hive-0.12.0/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home//bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

I also read that it can be changed in .bashrc or .bash_profile. Both these files contain this -

```
export PATH=$PATH
```

So I am not sure in which file I have to make the changes and what changes should I be making.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first one, change to:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

And for the second one, change to:

```
export PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH
```

This works by overriding whatever path to Java already exists in `$PATH`.

You shouldn't need double slash `//` after `Home`.

Answer (score 0):

> With Mountain Lion /etc/launchd.conf is where you should set the GUI applications Path. Remember it's not a script file; it only supports launchctl commands.

Source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63662/how-to-change-path-environment-variable-to-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-that-will-be

You should try editing launchd.conf to remove the paths that you don't need.

Comment: I personally don't have a Mac and cannot check the veracity of this answer.